# What strategy should I use to periodically extract information from a specific folder

Tags: python, database, scheduled-tasks

With this question I would like to gain some insights/verify that I'm on the right track with my thinking.

The request is as follows: I would like to create a database on a server. This database should be updated periodically by adding information that is present in a certain folder, on a different computer. Both the server and the computer will be within the same network (I may be running into some firewall issues).

So the method I am thinking of using is as follows. Create a tunnel between the two systems. I will run a script that periodically (hourly or daily) searches through the specified directory, convert the files to data and add it to the database. I am planning to use python, which I am fairly familiar with.

Note: I dont think I will be able to install python on the pc with the files.

Is this at all doable? Is my approach solid? Please let me know if additional information is required.

Answer (score 1):

> Create a tunnel between the two systems.

If you mean setup the firewall between the two machines to allow connection, then yeah. Just open the postgresql port. Check postgresql.conf for the port number in case it isn't the default. Also put the correct permissions in pg_hba.conf so the computer's ip can connect to it.

> I will run a script that periodically (hourly or daily) searches through the specified directory, convert the files to data and add it to the database. I am planning to use python, which I am fairly familiar with.

Yeah, that's pretty standard. No problem.

> Note: I dont think I will be able to install python on the pc with the files.

On Windows you can install anaconda for all users or just the current user. The latter doesn't require admin privileges, so that may help.

If you can't install python, then you can use some python tools to turn your python program into an executable that contains all the libraries, so you just have to drop that into a folder on the computer and execute it.

If you absolutely cannot install anything or execute any program, then you'll have to create a scheduled task to copy the data to a computer that has python over the network, and run the python script there, but that's extra complication.

If the source computer is automatically backed up to a server, you can also use the backup as a data source, but there will be a delay depending on how often it runs.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! One potential issue (I am not familiar with the matter) is that the server will be running on linux and the desktop will be running windows 10. But I think I will be able to work arround that. A friend suggested using cronjob to schedule the task so that is what I will try first.

Comment: No problem connecting windows postgres client to linux postgres server, but as said above make sure the client ip is authorized in pg_hba.conf. Cron is a linux tool, so if the desktop runs windows 10 it won't have cron, use task scheduler instead.